# MongoDB replication and failover with just two server instances

Tags: mongodb

So I'm in the process of laying out an architecture for a system that I intend to build myself. One of the features of the system should be, that it comprise redundancy - So that server B can take over in the event that Server A fails.

The problem is, that I know MongoDB supports replication with failover - However, just not when you only have 2 MongoDB instances (Because a single MongoDB instance can't appoint itself as primary).

As I see it, I therefore have 2 options:

1. Have a small service, that listens to the MongoDB changestream on server A and synchronize with server B at every change event
2. Use replication and accept that failover is not supported (Write a failover script to manually appoint a primary based on my own rules)

I don't have much practical experience with MongoDB, thus why I would like to hear from you if:

- My two solutions are feasible
- What caveats I may run into

Comment: Run 3 servers..

Comment: Use an [Replica Set Arbiter](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/replica-set-arbiter/index.html)

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit Yes, that is a good idea. But this still requires me to setup 3 servers right? If I run 2 VM on one of the servers, the split-brain concern will still be there. Running 3 servers is a considerable expense in this scenario.

Comment: You could add the service on one of the existing servers. Of course, then you have only 50% fail over covered.

Comment: But that's a really bad solution too, because if server B breaks down - Then the primary db will stop functioning too.. right? Anyway, would it be a good idea to run the arbiter on an RPI? That's a slightly cheaper solution.